# Assertion failure when adding a CCParticleSystemQuad as child to LHSprite

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, levelhelper

I try to add a `CCParticleSystemQuad` as child to `LHSprite`:

```
player = [loader spriteWithUniqueName:@"player"];
NSAssert(player != nil, @"Couldn't find the player!");

// Particles
smokeParticles = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"smoke.plist"];
smokeParticles.position = ccp(-30.0, 0.0);
[player addChild:smokeParticles];
```

---

But I keep getting this error message:

```
2012-12-29 22:51:44.373 MyProject[15396:15203]
*** Assertion failure in -[LHSprite addChild:z:tag:],
/MyPath/MyProject/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:567
```

---

### Adding the `CCParticleSystemQuad` to the `CCLayer`

```
[self addChild:smokeParticles];
```

works just fine.

---

### `CCSprite.m`: Line 567

```
NSAssert([child isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]],
         @"CCSprite only supports CCSprites as children when using CCSpriteBatchNode");
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is given in assert message. It happens because CCSprite only supports CCSprites as children when using CCSpriteBatchNode. If you use CCSpriteBatchNode to draw a sprite, you can only add CCSprites as children to this sprite.

Comment: Is it possible to have a particle emitter as child? Or must I manually track position/rotation?

Comment: You can't add particle system as a child to the sprite if this sprite is added to sprite batch node.

Answer (score 0):

Inside LH in the Level Navigator - drag your sprite on top of the MAIN_LAYER - this will remove the sprite from the batch node and make it self rendered - now you will be able to add children to it via code. If you use a batch sprite, you can only add children to the sprite that have the same texture as the batch node (that is, uses the same image file)

for the LHParallaxNode - this does not add the particle/sprite to the node - it just moves it. So you should also add your particle to the layer

[self addChild:particle z:100];

then add it to the parallax node.

`Bogdan Vladu` the creator of LevelHelper says so..